# Django - How to create/apply a Serializer for a GET request?

Tags: python, django

Normally, I will do this to get request params

```
name_input = request.GET.get("name",None)
```

However, I would like to restrict only `string` value or `int` value. Moreover, to avoid params was sent empty like this :

```
http://url?name=&age=12
```

I suppose these problems could be address if I can apply `serializer` for `GET` request. But I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a serializer with two (or more ) fields

```
class QueryPramSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    age = serializers.IntegerField()
```

Then validate the query parameter by passing the data into the serializer as

```
serializer = QueryPramSerializer(data=request.GET)
serializer.is_valid(True)
print(serializer.validated_data)
```

I assume that you are using DRF, if so, you can make use of [**`request.query_params`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params) instead of `request.GET`

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this DRF using request params
:**

**models**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _


class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=50, unique=True)
  age = models.IntegerField(_("Age"))
```

**serializers**

```
from .models import  Person


  class PersonSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        name = serializers.CharField()
        age = serializers.IntegerField()
       class Meta:
           model = Person
```

**views**

```
from .models import  Person
from .serializers import PersonSerializer
from rest_framework import generics


class PersionList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = Person.objects.all()
        name = self.request.query_params.get('name', None)
        age = self.request.query_params.get('age', None)

        if name is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(name__icontains=name)
        if age is not  None:
             queryset = queryset.filter(age__in=age)
        return queryset
```